# Dash Streaming fails as new segments are not being downloaded

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, chromecast, google-cast, mpeg-dash

I am trying to perform live dash streaming on chrome cast using the google media player.The stream starts off just fine.There after it downloads around 20 seconds worth of data and plays, but no more segment requests are generated.After this it autoPauses dues to Underflow.Once underflow is detected the segments are requested and playback can only be resumed after getting about 20 seconds worth of data.

1. Even after downloading a few segments(less than 20 seconds worth), the    player continues to detect underflow. In other words playback does not occur while segments are downloaded.

2.Requests for download are not created during playback(after the first 20 sec).

So the whole process seems like download 20 seconds - play - pause - download - play - etc.

- autoPauseDuration is 1 second
- autoResumeDuration is 2 seconds
- autoResumeNumberOfSegments is 2

The same live source is tested on chrome cast using another player and works successfully.

Comment: Have you referred to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player)? or at least try the samples provided?

Comment: Yes. As I have mentioned , the same setup is working successfully on another player. But I need it working using the native media player.

Comment: Are you using the CAF receiver?

Comment: No. CAF-receiver does not have this problem. Only observed in SDK v2 Receivers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by adding a parameter to the manifest.

```
MPD@mediaPresentationDuration
```

But some other player have played the content from same manifest without any trouble.